# Is it possible to hide "try now" button from the store while keeping link to instant app activated?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I added instant app compatibility to my Android application. It works : I have a "try now" button in the store (internal tests) and I can access my instant app with a link.

I would like to hide the "try now" button. I would like my instant app to be only accessible with the link.

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but it’s not possible to launch Instant Apps with links without the “Try Now” launch link in the Playstore.  If you would like this as a new feature, post here and they will look at your request:
[Request new feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787)

Comment: hey, any news on this topic ? it seems here is still nothing changed from 2019? :(